# Compare variables and return the relation of the first ones that are not equal in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I have a C++ function that is called frequently within a loop. It compares the variables `v_1`, `v_2` and `v_3` with type `double` of two objects `a` and `b` of a class `MyClass` in the following way:

```
// a, b are objects of a class MyClass
// v_1, v_2 and v_3 are class variables of type double

bool compare(MyClass const *a, MyClass const *b) const {

    if(a->v_1 != b->v_1) {

        return(a->v_1 > b->v_1);   // Usual case
    }

    else if(a->v_2 != b->v_2) {

        return (a->v_2 < b->v_2);  // Happens quite some times
    }

    else {

        return (a->v_3 < b->v_3);  // Unusual case
    }
}
```

I suspect that there is a better/easier way to implement this functionality. Do you have an idea on how to improve both style and, if possible, also efficiency of this function?

Comment: Is it intended that the first comparison uses `>` while the other 2 use `<`?

Comment: Can you explain at a high level what `compare` does? It doesn't seem to be simply comparing `MyClass`s but do something more complicated instead.

Comment: @nwp Regarding your first comment, yes that's intended.

Comment: @nwp Regarding your second comment, the function is actually a comparison that is used for picking objects of `Myclass` from a priority queue based on the comparisons shown there.

Comment: There really isn't enough context to properly review this - for instance, you've omitted the definition of the (vaguely-named) `MyClass`.  Depending on the types of its members, you might be able to write a clearer one-liner such as `return std::tie(b->v1, a->v2, a->v3) < std::tie(a->v1, b->v2, b->v3);`.

Comment: @TobySpeight It says they are `double`s in the comment. Never mind about the `std::tie`, you did a neat switcheroo there.

Answer (score 2):

## Naming

`MyClass` is a poor name for a type - type names should convey what they are *used for*.

## Encapsulation

The `compare()` appears to be a member function (as it has a `const` decoration).  If it's a member of `MyClass`, then it should either be `static` instead, or it should use the `this` argument it implicitly receives.  And it could be named `operator<` instead, to increase its utility:

```
bool MyClass::operator<(const MyClass& other) const
```

If it's not a member function, then the `const` is a syntax error.  Not only that, but it implies that the members of `MyClass` are public, which seems wrong for a "class" (as opposed to a struct).

## Implementation

Comparing pairs of values in turn until a pair is unequal is a common pattern, and the usual means to make it short and clear is to make use of the built-in less-than operator of `std::tuple`, something like this:

```
// Note that `v1` sorts in descending order, so is swapped in the tuples
return std::make_tuple(other.v1,       v2,       v3)
     < std::make_tuple(      v1, other.v2, other.v3);
```

If you don't want to copy the members (perhaps they are of class type), you could use `std::tie()` instead of `std::make_tuple()`, to compare through references instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! The original code has more useful variable names, of course. Regarding encapsulation and implementation, I will try the things you suggested and post again what I've decided to use. As you might notice, I'm a beginner at C++, so thanks for pointing it out the `std::tie` function!